# How to get the grep command to search a specified directory?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I am trying to create a `bash` command that uses `grep` to search arguments in a specified directory. How would I do this. At the moment it only searches for the current directory. I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
ls $directoryName -l | grep "$1"
```

Comment: In simplest cases, for example: `grep "$1" "$directoryName/*"`. For more flexibility, you might want to consider: `find "$directoryName" -type f -exec grep "$1" {} +`.

Comment: have you tried `grep -r $1 $directory`? (`-r` makes grep recursive)

Comment: @NimaGhotbi well whenever i do it gives me error. line 4: /a/directory: is a directory.

Comment: In your original post, what exact output do you see from your command `ls $directoryName -l | grep "$1"` ?

Comment: @RobDavis the output i get is >>>>      ./exampleFolder: line 4: /home/../../../.exampleFolder: Is a directory

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way do do this but

```
ls -lah $directoryName > /usr/tmp/test
grep $1 /usr/tmp/test
rm /usr/tmp/test
```

Edit: You might have better luck using `find` though.

`find $directoryName -name $1`

Answer (score 0):

Working example:
grep -e "Exec" /usr/share/applications/*

Answer (score 0):

The following example will search recursively (including in sub-folders and hidden files) for an argument or pattern in a literal way (it will search for '$1' literally, not allowing substitution):

```
grep -re '$1' /folder/folder
```

Now, if you want to search for the value of the argument, then the code below would allow for substitution and do that:

```
grep -re "$1" /folder/folder
```